# Sort the array inside object mongodb laravel

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I have this object and i want to sort the Demo2 by it created_at.
 I am using mongodb as db laravel php

```
Demo": {
    "Demo2": [
    { 
    "type": "review",       
    "created_at": "1970-01-01 05:30:00"
    },
    {
    "type": "store",        
    "created_at": "2019-04-16 6:22:30"
    },
    {
    "type": "postw",        
    "created_at": "2019-04-16 16:23:10"
   }

  ],

}
```

How can i achive this throught laravel mongodb query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **you need to use Aggregation Framework to get this done**

   > ```
   >  db.test.aggregate( [
   >   { $unwind: "$Demo.Demo2" },
   >   { $sort: { 'Demo.Demo2.created_at': -1}},
   >   {$group : {"_id": "1", "Demo2": {"$push": "$Demo.Demo2"}}}
   >   ]
   > )
   > ```

---

Comment: i try the solution but it returns only single record{
    "type": "postw",        
    "created_at": "2019-04-16 16:23:10"
   }

Comment: What is the your expected output ?

Comment: expected output Demo": {
    "Demo2": [{
    "type": "postw",        
    "created_at": "2019-04-16 16:23:10"
   },{
    "type": "store",        
    "created_at": "2019-04-16 6:22:30"
    },{ 
    "type": "review",       
    "created_at": "1970-01-01 05:30:00"
    },